# Highcharts synchronized charts with multiple axes datasets

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, synchronized

I am attempting to build a list of highcharts with weather data. Ultimately, there will be about 5 synchronized charts all with a date xAxis. The catch is, that each of those 5 charts will have at least 2 yAxis. I am trying to use this method in the Highchart synchronized charts example to eliminate the excessive breakdown of a ton of x and y axis settings.

Data Format:

```
  "datasets": [
      {
        "name": "Temperature", 
        "data": [[1464796500000, 70.34],[ 1464796800000, 70.52],[ 1464797100000, 70.52],[ 1464797400000, 70.7],[ 1464797700000, 70.88]], 
        "unit": "F", 
        "type": "area", 
        "valueDecimals": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Dewpoint", 
        "data": [[ 1464796500000, 66.94],[ 1464796800000, 66.79],[ 1464797100000, 66.79],[ 1464797400000, 66.97],[ 1464797700000, 67.47]], 
        "unit": "F", 
        "type": "area", 
        "valueDecimals": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Relative Humidity", 
        "data": [[ 1464796500000, 89],[ 1464796800000, 88],[ 1464797100000, 88],[ 1464797400000, 88],[ 1464797700000, 89]], 
        "unit": "%", 
        "type": "line", 
        "valueDecimals": 1
      }
  ]
```

My modified version of the Highchart api synchronized charts example: http://jsfiddle.net/bbw37zen/14/

What I really like about this example is that the dataset has all the info needed and you simply run this code to add it to the chart.

```
series: [{
    data: dataset.data,
    name: dataset.name,
    type: dataset.type,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
    }
}]
```

So, now for the main question. 
**In this example, how could I combine the Temperature and Dewpoint into the same graph (two y axes sharing the same xAxis date). I would want to try to keep the data in the format it is. Is it possible to join two datasets using this method? Or would I have to break down the yAxis options/data using a method like this - http://jsfiddle.net/kmuhw0zf/3/ ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question!

The demo iterates over several sets of data, adding each chart to the `container` `<div>` element. If you wanted to have multiple synchronized charts, but have one with multiple series, you will have to split them out. It's less efficient than the demo, but it should get you the customization you need.

I imagine it would work like this:

1. Define each chart and its options individually, setting them to their own variable.
2. For your mixed temperature/dewpoint graph, add both data sets as separate series in that specific chart's options.
3. Make sure each chart's `xAxis.events` attribute includes `setExtremes: syncExtremes`.
4. Once you've defined the options for each of your charts and assigned the data, use the jQuery `appendTo()` function to add them to the `container` `<div>` element, one by one:

   ```
   $("<div class='CHART1'>").appendTo("#container").highcharts(chartOptions_CHART1);
   $("<div class='CHART2'>").appendTo("#container").highcharts(chartOptions_CHART2);
   // ... and so on
   ```

In order for the syncronization to work, each chart will need to live in the `container` `<div>`.

> **Update:** After reading the associated comment from the original poster, I had another idea to try out that may be more efficient.

Theoretically, there's no reason why each item in your dataset couldn't include both items you want to chart. So, in your case, package the items that will share the same chart as unique name and data elements in your JSON array:

```
"datasets": [
    {
        "nameA": "Temperature", 
        "dataA": [[1464796500000, 70.34],[ 1464796800000, 70.52],[ 1464797100000, 70.52],[ 1464797400000, 70.7],[ 1464797700000, 70.88]], 
        "nameB": "Dewpoint", 
        "dataB": [[ 1464796500000, 66.94],[ 1464796800000, 66.79],[ 1464797100000, 66.79],[ 1464797400000, 66.97],[ 1464797700000, 67.47]], 
        "unit": "F", 
        "type": "area", 
        "valueDecimals": 1
    },
    ...
]
```

I'm assuming here that `unit`, `type`, and `valueDecimals` are in common. If you wanted to make those distinct, just make duplicates of those as well.

Here's how you would render that in your options:

```
series: [{
    data: dataset.dataA,
    name: dataset.nameA,
    type: dataset.type,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
    },
    yAxis: 0
}, {
    data: dataset.dataB,
    name: dataset.nameB,
    type: dataset.type,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
    },
    yAxis: 1
}]
```

This way, you could keep the simplicity of the original fiddle with the your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This does seem to work well. Although, there is most likely no way around some extra configuration for secondary y axes. I have an updated jsfiddle with a lot of improvements on the original version. It is getting closer to what I need. I will keep the question "unsolved" for a bit in case of the possibility of another solution. http://jsfiddle.net/bbw37zen/30/

Comment: @KyleDavis I appreciate your feedback. I got an epiphany after reading your comment and updated my answer. Let me know if this helps you as well.

Comment: Thanks again. Great idea! I will continue to to explore this and see what works best. I am trying to streamline this as much as possible. The final product will be quite complex with a very dynamic approach to choosing what meteorological parameters you want to see and which ones need plotted together. I am definitely on the right track!

Comment: ALSO, just realized, I can make yAxis settings a lot more dynamic as well! I can add more settings/options in the dataset and just point yAxis parameters to those values. I'd rather the data hold the options and the code just plug it all in automatically!

Answer (score 0):

Specify which y-axis to use. You can include multiple y-axes per chart; you just have to specify.

In your javascript dataset call:

```
"datasets": [
  {
    "name": "Temperature", 
    "data": [[1464796500000, 70.34],[ 1464796800000, 70.52],[ 1464797100000, 70.52],[ 1464797400000, 70.7],[ 1464797700000, 70.88]], 
    "unit": "F", 
    "type": "area", 
    "valueDecimals": 1,
    **"yAxis": 0**
  }      
]
```

They are 0 based, so specifiy it that way, or give the axis an id. Specific the axis in your chart  init.

```
$('chart').highCharts({
yAxis :[ 
  {
  //define axis info
  },
  {
  //Axis 2 info
  }
]
});
```

If you want the axis to appear on the right side, simply add `'opposite': true' to your axis definition.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis

Comment: Thanks amoyer. I did end up using a combo of this and the answer from brightmatrix. I'd like to figure out a way to add in all of the yAxis info into the dataset. I guess it could work in the same way as the dynamic xAxis info.